# How to connect data of add user new field with content type new field?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I have created a new field in add user in Drupal 7.

path : config/people/accounts/fields.

The field is of list type, say for listing 4 options. (Eg: ab, abc, abcd ,abcde.)

I have added a new user by clicking on one option. (assume it as abcd)

In database user added with that certain option. (eg : abcd)

I have created one content type with the same name of fields which is a text field. (it is visible in one of the forms in my drupal 7 page.)

path : structure/types/manage/innovation/fields.

Whenever I logged in as that new user that content type has to show that account field option (eg: abcd) which I gave while creating that user.

Is there any way to connect the Data of the account field and content type field?

I want that option to visible as a fixed option in the content 
type field.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: make a custom template for the user page/block

Comment: I added a custom module but while saving the module I'm getting an error. I tried to clear the cache data the same error is displaying. Fatal error: cannot declare class entityreference_behaviorhandler_broken, because the name is already in use.